# rosmake does not respect ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS or --pjobs

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosmake, parallel, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake in ROS fuerte does not seem to respect the ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-jN environment variable nor the --pjobs=N command line option for compiling with N+1 processes.

Instead, the number of rosmake instances spawned is always equal to the number of cores detected (regardless of whether or not that is more or fewer than the number specified via ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS or --pjobs).

The [ROS wiki page on environment variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) says setting ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS *should* work, but I have multiple installations of ROS that display this behavior.

Has anyone else had this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56404/rosmake-does-not-respect-ros_parallel_jobs-or---pjobs/) by [yoos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1207/yoos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That bug is known:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4036
https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/4
and a fix will be soon be released for fuerte and later.

In the meantime a workaround is using this (for experts):

```
export MAKEFLAGS="-j8"
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0